# how do I combine two or more variables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Here is an example

Variable 1:

```
$encodedtoday = MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->where('encoded_by', 'Mark')->count();
```

Variable 2:

```
$encodedtoday = MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->where('encoded_by', 'Michael')->count();
```

Variable 3:

```
$encodedtoday = MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->where('encoded_by', 'John')->count();
```

I know this can be done in array or something. Please show me

Comment: Your example happens to be something that can easily be solved via the query builder. Is it the only use case you have or is the problem more general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a array for encoded by names and then pass to whereIn condition as follow:

```
$encoded_by = ['Mark','Michael','John'];
$encodedtoday = MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today)
->whereIn('encoded_by', $encoded_by)->count();
return $encodedtoday;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$encodedtoday = MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->whereIn('encoded_by', ['Mark','Michael','John'])->count();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can define `$encodedtoday = 0;`
then keep adding count for all like this:

```
$encodedtoday += MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->where('encoded_by', 'Mark')->count();

$encodedtoday += MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->where('encoded_by', 'Michael')->count();

$encodedtoday += MemberProfile::whereDate('created_at', '=', $today )
->where('encoded_by', 'John')->count();
```

So here, `$encodedtoday` will have final count.